# How to initialize firebase in HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I have added the following scripts in my index.html

```html
<script src="/__/firebase/8.2.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="/__/firebase/8.1.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="/__/firebase/8.1.2/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
```

and then i'm trying to set authentication in a separate file which is

```js
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBgK4ZLhlKD4vvqqAmxHPXPOkW02_3MBDw",
    authDomain: "bitrupt-trainee-web.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://bitrupt-trainee-web-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "bitrupt-trainee-web",
    storageBucket: "bitrupt-trainee-web.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "151546755005",
    appId: "1:151546755005:web:f459ab08f7fd0f13b6c4d4",
};
const firebase = firebase.initalizeApp(firebaseConfig);

const auth = firebase.auth();
const db = firebase.firestore();

const signup = document.getElementById("sign-up-btn");

signup.onclick = function () {
    const email = document.getElementById("signup-email").value;
    const password = document.getElementById("signup-password").value;
    console.log(email, password);
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((cred) => {
        console.log(cred);
    });
};
```

but i'm getting the error 'cannot access firebase before initialization'
did i miss some step in the setup as in any other link i should've added too in index.html?

Comment: where are you adding the scripts in the index.html?

Comment: What's in the console? Are all the firebase libraries loading properly?

Comment: @PeterHaddad under the <body></body>

Comment: @Beerswiller it just shows 'cannot access firebase before initialization'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URLs you are using which begin with `/__` are reserved URLs to be used **when you use Firebase Hosting**, see the doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reserved-urls) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize).

They will work correctly "when you deploy to Firebase (`firebase deploy`) or when you run your app on a local server (`firebase serve`)".

If you use another hosting solution or try to execute your HTML page directly from your file system, it will not work.

---

I understand that the JS file you shared in your question is the `init.js` file that you declared with  `<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>` in your `index.html` file.

Using the  `/__` path prefix for your own JS file will not work: in other words you can't use reserved URLs for your own files. You need, in your `index.html` file, to point to the path of the `init.js` file under your root directory (which is named `public` by default, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/quickstart#initialize).

In other words, if `index.html` and `init.js` are in the same `public` folder, just do `<script src="init.js"></script>`.

Answer (score 0):

Without more info, I'll eave this here in case it helps

This goes at the bottom of `<body>`, just before the `</body>` tag

```
<!-- Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<!-- If you enabled Analytics in your project, add the Firebase SDK for Analytics -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<!-- Add Firebase products that you want to use -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>

<!-- initialize app -->
<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
```

Comment: the links which i took from my firebase project doesn't contain gstatic.com. i guess it's for the older version or something. do i need to use the same links you've mentioned here. are they valid now?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be useful for someone who stuck for hours like me figuring out things.

If you are serving your application through **Firebase Hosting**. In order to use the `firebase` class provided by the initialization script. I've done as below but nothing showed up.

```html
<script src='/__/firebase/init.js'>
 const db = firebase.firestore()
</script>
```

Turns out, you need to create another script tag or an external script **after** the initialization script.

```html
<script src='/__/firebase/init.js'></script>

<script>
 const db = firebase.firestore();
</script>
```